# Update Center launcher not found for GlassFish Server

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, netbeans-8

So I'm going through the Java EE 7 Tutorial, and on [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/usingexamples008.htm) they tell us how to update the tutorial. The problem is, when I try to follow the steps to try and update the tutorial from the netbeans IDE, I get the following error

> Update Center launcher not found for GlassFish Server

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't update the tutorial either (on Windows 10), despite there being four possible ways to do that using Glassfish 4.1.2:

[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484789/java-ee-7-first-cup-tutorial-cant-install-glassfish-4-update-center) If I select **View Domain Update Center** from the popup menu for the Glassfish Server:

- I get the error *Error: Unable to access jarfile C:\glassfish412\bin\..\pkg/lib/pkg-client.jar*.
- I also see this error in the server log: *Warning: Cannot create update center Image for C:\glassfish412; Update Center functionality will not be available in Admin Console*

[2](https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/toc.html) If I open a Command Prompt window and run **updatetool.bat** I get a SocketException. See SO question [JAVA EE 7 First cup tutorial, can't install Glassfish 4 update center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19484789/java-ee-7-first-cup-tutorial-cant-install-glassfish-4-update-center). Increasing the timeout didn't help.

[3](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html) If I open a Command Prompt window and run **pkg.bat** (the command line equivalent of the Update Tool) I get the error *Input/output error: Connection reset*.

[4] If I try to download **UpdateTool** from Glassfish's admin console (http://localhost:4848) there is nothing offered for update.

For several reasons I don't think it is now possible to update the Tutorial:

- The nature of the errors suggests that the core problem is that there is nothing available to download. It's not a networking or timeout problem.
- Java EE8 is available, so Oracle are unlikely to worry much about problems with a tutorial for EE7.
- Oracle are actively in the process of handing EE over to Eclipse, so they are unlikely to be concerned about issues with an EE tutorial, and may be actively distancing themselves from their EE offerings such as software supporting tutorials. (This is just speculation on my part; I have no supporting evidence).

---

Update based on OP comment:

All that said, Oracle also provides tutorials for **EE 8** which may be more user firendly:

- The "[Your First Cup](https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/toc.html)" tutorial for EE 8.
- A longer general tutorial for EE 8 titled "[The Java EE Tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/toc.html)".

Comment: I wish there was an EE8 tutorial.

Comment: @Rockstar5645 There are EE8 tutorials available. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The update center is now gone forever and you cannot see the release.glassfish.org domain, so it's gone for version 4.

With the release of Glassfish 5 they have removed those binaries also.

and there are no workaround possible. you have to manually update the glassfish server.

Please see the link below and serach for "update tool".

https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/release-notes.pdf

Answer (score 0):

In Glassfish 5, you don't need to use Update Center Tool to perform any update for downloading "firstcup" tutorial. 
All you need is to download Oracle SDK 8 located at this url :https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-downloads-3908423.html.

After this, unzip the file downloaded and it will be used as your Glassfish server folder. 
Hope, it helps