# Where is the "Java EE "Your First Cup" Tutorial" download for installation?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I am trying to follow this tutorial, but at [this page](https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/creating-example002.html#GCRKM) it has the line

"In NetBeans IDE select File, then Open Project, navigate to the location where you installed the tutorial (usually glassfish5/docs/firstcup),"

The problem is that nowhere above this line is there any text that specifies installing the tutorial.

What am I missing here?  I have looked at JEE7 and JEE8 tutorials and they both assume this step, but nowhere is this step to be found.  In the JEE7 tutorial there is a step "Getting the Latest Updates to the Tutorial" but the connection from my glassfish server keeps bombing out, and in any case, this is to get any updates to "the tutorial". I have no idea what I'm supposed to be installing before I get going on this tutorial, which is maddening.  Thanks.

Comment: It's not a good sign that the tutorial asks you to use the old java.util.Calendar classes. Maybe find something better.

Comment: I see your point but that's probably throwing the baby out with the bathwater. The tutorial is not there to teach Java 8 APIs, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem is that nowhere above this line is there any text that
>   specifies installing the tutorial. What am I missing here?

You have a point, and you are not missing anything obvious. While the tutorial itself is fine, the documentation on how to set it up is incredibly confusing. In particular:

- Once you are within the tutorial no link is provided to the source of the project files, although links are still given to everything else you need (JDK, Glassfish, etc.). It is ridiculous and counterintuitive that you cannot obtain the files you require for the tutorial from within the tutorial.
- Two sets of downloadable tutorial files are provided, and the distinction between them is not made clear:

  1. The source files used in the tutorial (**.java*, **.xml*, etc.), which is what you need.
  2. The files that actually comprise the tutorial (**.adoc*), which most developers won't care about.
- The documentation mentions two projects: The *First Cup of Java EE Tutorial* and *The Java EE Tutorial*. Despite their similar names these are completely different projects!
- The link to download the source for the *First Cup Tutorial* is bizarrely provided in a section titled *"Related Projects"* instead of the section titled *About this Project*.

The link to the source used for the project is provided on the homepage of the [First Cup of Java EE Tutorial](https://javaee.github.io/firstcup/). However, don't click the links titled *Sources* and *Download* on the right of that page. Though it is not obvious, those links relate to the tutorial itself.

Instead, in the section titled *Related Projects* click the link titled [javaee/firstcup-examples](https://github.com/javaee/firstcup-examples) which sends you to GitHub for the project source files:

[image: firstCupTutorial]

> In the JEE7 tutorial there is a step "Getting the Latest Updates to
>   the Tutorial" but the connection from my glassfish server keeps
>   bombing out...

See [Update Center launcher not found for GlassFish Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49597873/2985643). Although Glassfish is the Java EE Reference Implementation, it is in the process of being migrated from Oracle to the Eclipse Foundation, and I suspect Oracle are no longer very zealous about addressing issues with Glassfish. Stick with the EE 8 tutorial instead, if possible.

Comment: That's a good expansive explanation, and it encapsulates in full my experience in making my way through the tutorial.  As it turns out, it's a good tutorial. You can get quite a lot out of it by forensically examining the finished code in the project.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution:
If you have downloaded the respective Java SDK, then the first-cup project along with samples projects are being availed in the below mentioned folder structure.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing but I think what one needs to do is

- create a project directory
- cd into that directory
- clone the project's git repository i.e.

`git clone https://github.com/javaee/firstcup-examples.git`

Then one can proceed (hopefully) with the rest of the tutorial.

Comment: That is correct (for now), though a safer approach would be to download the code through the link provided by Oracle, as described in my answer.